# AD-AS Analysis of the Effects of a Decrease in Corporation Tax

Tags: macroeconomics

As a result of a decrease in corporation tax, which curve shifts to the right first? Does AD shift to the right first or does SRAS shift to the right?

My argument is that a decrease in corporation tax causes post-tax profits to rise as the cost of production decreases, resulting in an incentive for corporations to increase supply. The supply curve shifts to the right.
Alternatively, it has been argued that AD shifts to the right first as corporations react to tax cuts by increasing investment, causing demand-pull inflation.

Is it the case that AD always shifts before SRAS?